# cannot override plesk vhost.conf httpdmng failed

Tags: plesk, vhosts

I'm trying to override the plesk vhost.conf settings. However I've tried all the guides, I've changed the following

```
/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.com/conf/vhost.conf
```

which in the guidance you should do then run this command to override -

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=myhostname.com
```

This gives the following error -

```
  WARNING: You are using obsolete option, use corresponding option of  httpdmng. 
 websrvmng: /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng execution failed: 
  fork_execv: execv("/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng") failed: No such   file or directory 
websrvmng: /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng execution failed: 
        fork_execv: execv("/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng") failed: No   such file or directory
```

not sure is there's another way, but configure seems to default to last_httpd.conf??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use direct command

/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain domain.com

What is your Plesk version? File /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng is a part of plesk-core package.